# Contar numero de filas php

Tags: php, html

Estoy tratando de contar el número de filas en función de un `WHERE` en php pero cuando lo ejecuto me lanza un error.

**Código para contar**

```
public function mostrarRollosModel($tabla){

        $stmt = Conexion::conectar() -> prepare("SELECT cod_parte FROM $tabla WHERE es_rollo='S'");
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt -> fetchAll();
        $numero_filas = mysqli_num_rows($stmt);
        return $numero_filas;
        $stmt->close();
    }
```

**Error que me lanza**

```
Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Inventarios\models\Rollos.php on line 13
```

¿Como puedo resolver este error? Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás mezclando código de dos API distintas: mysqli y PDO.

El mensaje de error de tu comentario indica que estás usando PDO. Entonces para obtener el número de filas puedes usar [`rowCount`](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.rowcount.php):

```
public function mostrarRollosModel($tabla){

        $stmt = Conexion::conectar() -> prepare("SELECT cod_parte FROM $tabla WHERE es_rollo='S'");
        $stmt->execute();
        //$stmt -> fetchAll(); No es necesario si usas rowCount()            
        $numero_filas = $stmt-rowCount();
        $stmt->close();
        return $numero_filas;
```

En el código he corregido dos cositas más:

- he puesto todo orientado a objetos, pues en esta línea `$numero_filas = mysqli_num_rows($stmt);` estabas usando el modo procedural. La mezcla de estilos es desaconsejada.
- he cerrado el `$stmt` antes del `return`. Lo que hay después de `return` no se ejecuta.
- si usas `rowCount()` no es necesario el uso de `fetchAll`. Y si usas `fetchAll`, puedes prescindir del uso de `rowCount`. Por ejemplo:

  ```
      $arrDatos=$stmt -> fetchAll();             
      $numero_filas = count($arrDatos);
  ```

  Esta forma es conveniente si al mismo tiempo vas a trabajar con los datos. Ya que evitas una llamada suplementaria a `rowCount`. Contando cuántas filas tiene el array que te devuelve `fetchAll` ya sabes cuantas filas hay.

Comment: Si utilizo tu metodo me muestra este error:
`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::store_result() in `

Comment: Ah, entonces estás usando PDO. Al ver esto `mysqli_num_rows` pensé que usabas `mysqli`. Ahora edito la respuesta.